# Static Variable re-initialization solution

Tags: c

Static variable re initialization:In the second part of the code i reinitialize the static variable x to 5. o/p of the first code is as expected but why o/p of the second part is 6 6 why not 6 7.

```
void foo()
{
    static int x ;
    x++;
    printf("%d", x);
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    foo();
    return 0;
}

//output will be 1 2

//But if i re initialize the static variable then why the output is like this:

void foo()
{
    static int x ;
    x=5;
    x++;
    printf("%d", x);
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    foo();
    return 0;
} 

//output is 66 why not 67
```

Answer (score 4):

The result of:

```
x = 5;
x++;
```

is that `x` is 6. Since you execute this code twice you get the output `66`.

Note, `x = 5;` is an assignment, not an initialization.

Comment: +1 For emphasizing the difference between assignment and initialization.

Comment: yes it is assigned to 5 . if it gives output as 6 6 then what is the use of static variable here?

Comment: I just want to know why static is not effective in the second code.

Comment: It is effective in the second code.  I don't know why you would expect `67` to appear, can you explain?  What do you think `x = 5;` does?

Answer (score 1):

The output is 6, 6 because you reinitialize it to 5 each time you call the function.

To initialize it only once (and get 6, 7) you need to write:

```
static int x = 5;
```

Furthermore, the first code may yield unexpected results, because the variable is uninitialized and may contain any value.

Comment: As far as i know static variables are by default initialized to 0 .
as static variables are stored in data segment . So the first code will give the expected result.

Comment: I just want to know why static is not effective in the second code.

Comment: @rabi The explanation as to why `static` is ineffective in the second code is given in the very first sentence. You set the value of x to 5 each time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

The result is as expected because, in the function foo(),

```
void foo()
{
    static int x ;
// what ever be the value of x until this point is retained.
// But what you are trying to do is assign the variable x again to 5, which means
// you are overwriting the previous value of x with 5.
    x=5;
    x++;
// Since x is always 5 due to overwriting, x++ will always yield "6" no matter what.
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

In this scenario, the keyword **static** does not have any effect on the output.

Comment: When ever you use static variables then you should initialize the value of the variable in the declaration itself and should not assign any value to it after that

Comment: @rabi, did you read the comment in the code? The value `5` is assigned to `x` every time the statement is met, that's all.

Comment: @Jens So can we say that static variables can be initialized only once and can be assigned multiple times?

Comment: @rabi, that is true for all variables. The difference is if the variable is declared `static`, there is only one incarnation of that variable for the whole execution. Other local variables have one incarnation at each time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo()
{
    static int x ;    // point 0
    x=5;    // point-1
    x++;    // point -2
    printf("%d", x);   // point- 3
}

int main()
{
    foo();    // exe-1
    foo();    // exe-2
    return 0;
}
```

The program execution flow and the value of x at that point

Irrespective of how many times foo() is called, point-0 will be called only once.

exe-1: (point-0)x=0--> (point-1)x=5 (assigned) --> (point-2)x= 6

**current value of x=6** before exe-2

exe-2: this time it doesn't comes to point-0, it comes to point-1, which is **overwritting** the current value of **x(which is 6) with 5** again. So, after this, when it comes to point-2, the value of x is incremented from 5 to 6, so it prints 6